# Blackberry data binding?

Tags: data-binding, blackberry

I think I already know the answer, but does BB (5.0 or earlier) have any support data binding to fields?

For example, if I have a vector of items, could I bind that to a list (or some field) that will get auto-updated when new data is placed into the vector?

I'm thinking that is something I'd have to write with the ListFieldCallback or it's equivalent in other fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement this using a homemade observer. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)  You could use a custom vector which was aware of the observer if you wanted to.  I've done this before and it works.

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly such funcionality is not available right out of the box.

As a starting point to `ListField` implementaion on BB, take a look at [Simple ListField example](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Simple-ListField-example/m-p/431294#M84639) by peter_strange.

Comment: However, maybe you already know how to implement ListField if you already say about ListFieldCallback...